# Stata: tsline graphs values not at the right date

Tags: stata, datetime-format, trendline

I want to depict the evolution of a variable called `share` over time. I do so by using `tsline`, but the resulting graph looks off: Although my data starts in May 1989 and ends in December 1993, the trendline is drawn so that it begins in January 1989 and ends in
mid-1993.

```
gen double time3 = monthly(time2, "YM")
format time3 %tm
tsset time3
tsline share, ///
    ttitle("years") ytitle("") ylabel(0(.2).65) ///
    tlabel(1989m5(12)1994m5, format(%tmY) labsize(small))
```

I know that Stata stores dates as integers and tried replacing the year-month-indications after `tlabel` by integers. Since the time variable is defined as months since `1960m1`, `1989m5` is stored internally as 352 and `1993m12` as 407. I learned this by running `dis tm(1989m5)`. But even with `tlabel(352(12)407)`, the trendline is not drawn correctly. Has anyone an idea about how to fix this? This is the [how the graph looks like by now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8fdc.png)

This is a subsample of the data that I used:

```
[CODE]
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str7 time2 double(time3 share)
"1989-05" 352  .1536926147704591
"1989-06" 353  .1665024630541872
"1989-08" 355 .12674650698602793
"1989-09" 356 .18095712861415753
"1989-10" 357 .24629080118694363
"1989-11" 358 .23008849557522124
"1989-12" 359 .17638036809815952
"1990-01" 360 .20521653543307086
"1990-02" 361  .1754473161033797
"1990-03" 362 .17401960784313725
"1990-04" 363 .14173998044965788
"1990-05" 364  .1669970267591675
"1990-06" 365  .1398838334946757
"1990-08" 367 .10461689587426326
"1990-09" 368 .14965312190287414
"1990-10" 369  .1921182266009852
"1990-11" 370 .18038617886178862
"1990-12" 371 .19577735124760076
"1991-01" 372 .10562685093780849
"1991-02" 373 .09596928982725528
"1991-03" 374  .1941747572815534
"1991-04" 375  .1889106967615309
"1991-05" 376  .1794234592445328
"1991-06" 377  .1968390804597701
"1991-08" 379 .17846309403437816
"1991-09" 380 .19425173439048563
"1991-10" 381 .14556962025316456
"1991-11" 382 .15569143932267168
"1991-12" 383  .1694015444015444
"1992-01" 384 .20812928501469147
"1992-02" 385   .257590597453477
"1992-03" 386  .2204724409448819
"1992-04" 387 .22096456692913385
"1992-05" 388 .21601941747572814
"1992-06" 389  .1675025075225677
"1992-07" 390 .22176591375770022
"1992-09" 392 .15128968253968253
"1992-10" 393 .15841584158415842
"1992-11" 394  .1849112426035503
"1992-12" 395 .19642857142857142
"1993-01" 396 .22469252601702933
"1993-02" 397  .2796528447444552
"1993-03" 398   .290811339198436
"1993-04" 399 .24108910891089108
"1993-05" 400  .2562437562437562
"1993-06" 401 .22127872127872128
"1993-07" 402 .27874743326488705
"1993-09" 404  .3391472868217054
"1993-10" 405  .3840155945419103
"1993-11" 406 .45184824902723736
"1993-12" 407 .43987975951903807
end
format %tm time3
[/CODE]
```

Comment: can you share the graph you get and at least a subset of the data? Use the tool `dataex` to share the data, so we can see if the variables are in the right format

Comment: Hi @ThelceBear, I edited my earlier post and included a data example as well as the graph that I am having troubles with. Thanks for hinting me towards dataex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph you've posted doesn't seem surprising.

Using the data and code you've posted

```
clear
input str7 time2 double(time3 share)
"1989-05" 352  .1536926147704591
"1989-06" 353  .1665024630541872
"1989-08" 355 .12674650698602793
"1989-09" 356 .18095712861415753
"2019-10" 717 .13052208835341367
"2019-11" 718 .13559059987631417
"2019-12" 719 .13997555012224938
end
format %tm time3

tsset time3
tsline share, ///
    ttitle("years") ytitle("") ylabel(0(.2).65) ///
    tlabel(1989m5(12)2019m12, format(%tmY) labsize(small))
```

it's hard to see what might be a problem.

`tsline` doesn't purport to draw a trend line, just a line graph for the data specified.

Comment: Hi @Nick, for making it easier to see what went wrong in the graph, I edited my data example such that it now covers a shorter time period. While doing so, I found the solution to my problem: When defining `tlabel(1989m1(12)1994m1)`, everything looks just the way it is supposed to be! Anyways, thank you for coming back to me:)